# Lambda to transform List into Map of shared values to lists of uniques values

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a List of `Foo` with two important properties, `Bar bar` and `Baz baz`. Instances may share `Bar` values but have unique `Baz`s.

I want to transform this List into a Map such that the unique `Baz` of all instances that share a `Bar` are put in a Set mapped to that shared `Bar`.

```
Map<Bar, Set<Baz>> m = new HashMap<>();
for (Foo foo : fooRepository.findAll()) {
    if (m.containsKey(foo.bar)) {
        m.get(foo.bar).add(foo.baz);
    } else {
        Set<Baz> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(foo.baz);
        m.put(foo.bar, set);
    }
}
```

My own functional chops have not proven up to the task. I've attempted to both `reduce` and `collect` the List but get tripped up by type problems when trying to implement the different parameters as lambdas.

Attempts using Collect

```
m = fooRepository.findAll().stream().collect(new HashMap<Bar, Set<Baz>>(), (m, foo)->m.merge(Foo::getBaz, s->s.add(foo.getBar()));
```

Incomplete, compiler can't determine types of m or foo and Foo::getBaz.

Reduce doesn't work because it doesn't allow the accumulator to be a different value from the elements.

Comment: Show some of your `collect` or `reduce` attempts.

Comment: Guava's [SetMultimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) might be a good fit, you could do this with `put(foo.bar, foo.baz)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Map<Bar, Set<Baz>> m = fooRepository.findAll()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getBar,
                Collectors.mapping(Foo::getBaz, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>
    upper bounds: java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>,java.lang.Object

It's disappointing how often I encounter these esoteric errors with streams that aren't the most rudimentary possible.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/BgO2pQ. Are you trying to cast to `HashMap`?

Comment: Doh, the field was infact typed as HashMap instead of Map! Stupid legacy code, I forgot to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a `Multimap` instead of a `Map` you can use `Collectors2.toSetMultimap` from [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

```
SetMultimap<Bar, Baz> multimap = fooRepository.findAll()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors2.toSetMultimap(Foo::getBar, Foo::getBaz));
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Comment: Or Guava's [`ImmutableSetMultimap.toImmutableSetMultimap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html#toImmutableSetMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)